# Show $\phi:H\to HN/N$ is one-to-one.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

Can anyone help me with the question? I am stuck on showing this is one-to-one.

> For subgroup $H$ of $G$ and normal subgroup $N$ in $G$, show the function $\phi:H\to HN/N$ defined by $\phi(h)=hN$ is one-to-one.

My work:

Let $\phi(h_{1})=\phi(h_{2})$. Then $h_{1}N=h_{2}N$. Then there is an $n\in N$ such that $h_{1}=h_{2}n$.

I feel like I need to use the fact that $h_{2}\in HN$?

Comment: The kernel of your $\phi$ is $H\cap N$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems. (Second iso theorem)  For instance, if $H=G$, you are looking at the map $\phi\colon G \to G/N$.

Comment: The result is not true.  But if you add the assumption that $H\cap N=\{e\}$ then you have $h_2^{-1}h_1\in N$ and $h_2^{-1}h_1\in H$, so $h_2^{-1}h_1=e$ and $h_1=h_2$.

Comment: Yes the result is not true consider the example G=Z, H=Z, N=2Z

Comment: @peterag I see! So I just need to show it is a homomorphism and then apply the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: We are (all) saying that your result is not true, as stated... The second iso theorem is that your (group homomorphism) $\phi$ descends to an iso  $H/ H\cap N \simeq HN/N$, with $H\cap N$ is normal in $H$, $HN$ a group, and $N$ normal in $HN$. As @David wrote: your statement is only true if $H\cap N = \{e \}$.

Comment: But in line with your question in your last comment: with the 'facts' of  my previous comment (along with $HN/N$ is a group, which I missed), the 2nd iso theorem is a consequence of the 1st. OK?